# An exponential limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+to+infty+(1-exp(na))%5E(1%2Fn)), for $a > 0$ $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - e^{na} \right)^{1/n} = e^a.$$
Is this easy to prove?

EDIT: Actually, in the case I need, $a < 0$. If I understood correctly this is covered by the answers below.

Comment: You get negative numbers to non-integer powers... Hm...

Comment: hint: pull  $e^{na}$ out of the brackets and taylor expand furhtermore  i think the minus sign should be in front of the $1$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Good point, didn't think about that right away. Wonder how Wolfram Alpha makes sense out of that.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä: Limits are computed from values *in the domain*.

Comment: We can write for $a>0$

$$\begin{align}
(1-e^{na})^{1/n}&=e^{\frac1n \log(1-e^{na})}\\\\
&=(e^{na}-1)^{1/n}e^{i\frac1n(2k+1)\pi}
\end{align}$$

Comment: You changed the sign of $a$ but accepted an answer correct only for $a>0$. The new limit is obviously $1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe I already mentioned this in the comments below my answer, so it is not a problem I do believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some algebra:

$$(1-e^{na})^{1/n}=e^a(-1)^{1/n}(1-e^{-na})^{1/n}$$

As $n\to\infty$, note that

$$(-1)^{1/n}=e^{\frac1n(2k+1)\pi i}\to\begin{cases}+1&;n\equiv0\pmod2\\-1&;n\equiv1\pmod2\end{cases}$$

The second limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-e^{-na})^{1/n}=(1-0)^0=1$$

Thus,

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-e^{na})^{1/n}=e^a\times1\times\pm1=\pm e^a$$

---

If, however, you stick to one branch and don't jump branches as $n\to\infty$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{1/n}=1^0=1$$

And thus, we get the different result of

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-e^{na})^{1/n}=e^a$$

Comment: You might consider noting that $(-1)^{1/n}=e^{i\frac1n(2k+1)\pi}$ is multivalued.  And regardless of this, the limit is $0$ as $n\to \infty$..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  (+1)

Comment: Thanks, actually when I double checked, in the case that's interesting for me, $a < 0$.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä If $a<0$, then just set $b=-a$ and don't factor out the $e^a$ in the beginning.  The rest of the steps are the same.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: hem, $e^{-\infty}=0$ and $1^0=1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, are you saying I could've skipped a few more steps?  Thanks.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: mh, maybe I am saying that $e^a$ doesn't hold...

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean?  I assume $a>0$ just as the OP wanted, and explained what to do if $a<0$ in the comments.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: ok.

Answer (score 2):

If we remain in the reals, for even $n$ the terms cease to exist after a short while, while for odd $n$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-e^{na})^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^{-na}-1)^{1/n}e^a=-e^a.$$

(But WA doesn't stay in the reals.)

---

**Update**:

For $a<0$, the expression tends to $1^0$.

Comment: Thanks, actually when I double checked, in my case $a<0$ and this should be valid for the entire sequence?

Comment: Oh, good point!  Hm... now why would Wolfram do this to me :-/